# Auto import modules with emacs-jedi

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, emacs-jedi, python-jedi

With ropemacs you can do something like this:

```
M-x rope-auto-import
```

This analyze the code (I presume) and imports missing modules, for example if I write:

```
datetime.now()
```

it should do the import for me by add this line:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

(it always uses the `from ... import ...` form)

Is there a similar function in emacs-jedi?

Comment: It might help if you explained what `rope-auto-import` does.

Comment: Some info here can be useful, about python-mode or a code snippet that uses `py-isort`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838515/auto-include-python-import-statements-in-vim-emacs Nothing's perfect though.

Comment: How/where can I install `rope-auto-import`?

Answer (score 3):

Jedi doesn't support auto imports, yet. (And therefore obviously emacs-jedi does neither)

There are [discussions](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/103#issuecomment-12242168) ongoing to implement refactorings as well (which includes auto imports). However, it will probably take another year or so.

Comment: It's now 8 years later.  Did this discussion go anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the jedi part and pay attention to the emacs part you could use the follow command after installing [autoimport](https://lyz-code.github.io/autoimport/).

```
(defun my-python-autoimports ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (shell-command (s-concat "autoimport " (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
  (revert-buffer t t))
```