# Vim plugin for automatically generating Python import statements (without using Rope)

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, rope

I've seen similar questions asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825073/is-there-a-plugin-for-vim-to-auto-import-python-libraries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838515/auto-include-python-import-statements-in-vim-emacs), however they are 4 years old and did not yield answers that matched my requirements.

If I type Python code into Vim, for example:

```
os.path.join('my', 'path')
resp = requests.get('http://example.com')
HttpResponse('success')
```

Assuming that I had the third-party modules 'requests' and 'django' in my site-packages folder, is there any Vim plugin -- which does not use the Rope library -- that could automatically add the relevant import statements to the Python file (both for built-in & third-party modules, using either `import` or `from` as needed), like this:

```
import os
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

While I would traditionally use the venerable Rope package, I have been replacing Rope functions with modern alternatives to avoid the overhead of the .ropeproject folder.  However, I haven't found a Vim alternative yet for auto-import.

Comment: What’s wrong with rope? It is under maintenance again, and one ``echo .ropeproject/ >>.git/info/exclude`` can cure all your problems, cannot it?

Comment: Okay there's https://lyz-code.github.io/autoimport/#alternatives , writing a vim plugin to do that should not be too hard

Comment: @user202729 There are thankfully now (6 years after I posted the question) some great solutions. For example, Neovim 0.5 (having built-in LSP support) paired with nvim-cmp and pyright can automatically add import statements when auto-completing a class or function name. Which is fantastic. Now if only auto-importing understood when it should import from parent modules rather than always from the bottom-most level, I'd be living the dream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using python-imports.vim (https://github.com/mgedmin/python-imports.vim). Combine that with gutentags plugin and it is almost perfect. Perfect solution would create all imports and magically guess correct modules in case of name collision but I doubt that this is possible.

Update 2022-05-14: Another way is to use Ale (https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) with pyright (https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) and :ALEImport command.

Comment: Some other caveats I noticed with this one is it will add the import from a submodule even when it's available from a parent module, and also it doesn't combine multiple imports from the same module on a single line, but overall this plugin accomplishes this task very well. Great find.

Comment: Use isort fixer with ale (recommended) or isort plugin to combine multiple imports. Report bug for first problem (or maybe even fix it).

Comment: I think this solution (as well as the **vimpy** solution below), requires the user to *put the cursor at the identifier* instead of go through the file automatically, unlike (supposedly) the solutions using [ropevim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081465/5267751) or [mr.igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860373/5267751).

Comment: I landed here after websearching for the 'autoimport' that `:ALEFixSuggest` recommends—I'm new to ALE (I've been using Syntastic for years, but it's deprecated now), so it's not clear to me exactly what it was referring to. Anyhow, I think you should've written a separate answer, instead of adding the update, but if I end up up-voting this answer, it'll be for that. ☺

Comment: I guess 2023/2024 answer would be neovim with LSP and pyright, but I don't want to write separate comment for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [vimpy](https://github.com/dbsr/vimpy). From its description it does what you are looking for.

Note that it requires [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes).

Comment: I've been trying to get vimpy working this week, but it produces errors.  I submitted a bug report on GitHub, but the maintainer no longer seems to actively maintain the project.  Last commit was over a year ago.  Have you successfully used this project?

Comment: I've never felt the need for it, so I haven't tried it.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the lead on it, in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but since this question exists, I might as well post a new answer.

I use [`coc-python`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python) for everything of this nature.

It just works like magic:

[image]

The only caveat is that you have to press `Ctrl-y` to accept the Auto-import suggestion.

Make sure you haven't got `Ctrl-y` mapped to anything else in insert mode (a common plugin called Emmet remaps this combination, for example.)